# kivymd 0.104.2dev: MDGridBottomSheet items call callback function twice

Tags: kivymd

Sorry for my English.
As per the title, after several searches and after trying the code on the dedicated page (*https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/components/bottom-sheet/*), the callback function is always called by each item twice.
I think it depends on the management of the events, however how can I solve without any bad workaround?
Thanks in advance.

Edit:from *https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/components/bottom-sheet/*:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder

from kivymd.toast import toast
from kivymd.uix.bottomsheet import MDGridBottomSheet
from kivymd.app import MDApp

KV = '''
Screen:

    MDToolbar:
        title: 'Example BottomSheet'
        pos_hint: {"top": 1}
        elevation: 10

    MDRaisedButton:
        text: "Open grid bottom sheet"
        on_release: app.show_example_grid_bottom_sheet()
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
'''


class Example(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

    def callback_for_menu_items(self, *args):
        print ('callback')

    def show_example_grid_bottom_sheet(self):
        bottom_sheet_menu = MDGridBottomSheet()
        data = {
            "Facebook": "facebook-box",
            "YouTube": "youtube",
            "Twitter": "twitter-box",
            "Da Cloud": "cloud-upload",
            "Camera": "camera",
        }
        for item in data.items():
            bottom_sheet_menu.add_item(
                item[0],
                lambda x, y=item[0]: self.callback_for_menu_items(y),
                icon_src=item[1],
            )
        bottom_sheet_menu.open()


Example().run()
```

Comment: Attach a minimal code that reproduces the error.

Comment: exemple attached